# Why Authorize.net is phasing out MD5 based hash use for transaction? SHA512 hash algorithm usage should solve the issue for now right?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize.net

I learned that [Authorize.net is phasing out MD5 based hash use for transaction](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/MD5-Hash-End-of-Life-Signature-Key-Replacement). Please let me know if this is an issue.

If we use SHA512 hash algorithm for fingerprint generation which when posted will generate signature key, that should solve the issue for now right?

Comment: As to the "why", I guess it is because MD5 is not considered "secure" any more for quite some time now. What "issues" are you expecting when using a more recent Hash Algorithm?

Comment: I am not facing any issues using recent Hash Algorithm. I were trying to know the security vulnerability with MD5.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 has not been considered secure for quite some time now thanks to collisions being found and rainbow tables allowing for easy cracking of those hash values.

As their documentation states switching to SHA512 will work and is required going forward.  MD5 will no longer work starting sometime around April. So your code with MD5 will work until then but you should update your code before the deadline approaches or you risk your code breaking.